# Setup POS with Apache OFBiz

Tags: apache, ofbiz

I am new to OFBiz and have been using `apache-ofbiz-16.11.01`. I need to connect the POS machine with OFBiz. I have gone through many websites but not getting any clear information. Does anyone know about how to set up the POS service with OFBiz. Only option available is webpos but I need to connect with terminal for card transactions.

In `apache-ofbiz-13.07.03` there is a option for pos. Once started the POS service what I have to do next.

Comment: What do you mean by setting up the POS service. Are you referring to adding the webpos plugin to the main application

Answer (score 1):

Here is an excerpt of [the POS official documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/OFBIZ/POS+System)

With  [OFBIZ-7804](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OFBIZ-7804) The POS has been pushed in  [OFBiz Attic](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/OFBIZ/OFBiz+Attic#OFBizAttic-POS).

The last released version with the POS available was R12.04.06. It's though still available in the R14.12 and 15.12 non released branches. It'll not be available with the R16 release and further. All the POS official documentationis reliable and usable before revision 1754402